# What kind of object has to be passed for JsonResult in MVC.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I'm passing a custom class to my controller and it seems that the JsonResult is not properly passed.

What bothers me is that (also the fullcalendar wont read the json) the console.log which I have in my view prints the path to the function (wtf?) instead of what Json shoul return

This is my code:

```
    public JsonResult GetCalendarEvents()
    {
        var eventList = BusinessLayer.Event.getAllEvents();

        return Json(eventList.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

What kind of object has to be passed for this to work?

My evenList is of type `List<Event>` from here:

```
    public static String ListToString(List<Event> evs)
    {
        String ret = "";
        foreach (var ev in evs)
        {
            ret += ev.ToString() + "\n";
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static List<Event> getAllEvents()
    {
        List<DataLayer.Event> dbEvents = DataApi.db.Event.ToList();
        List<Event> returnEvents = new List<Event>();
        foreach (DataLayer.Event oneEvent in dbEvents)
        {
            Event newEvent = new Event
            {
                ID = oneEvent.IDEvent,
                userID = oneEvent.UserID,
                projectID = oneEvent.ProjectID,
                jobtypeID = oneEvent.JobTypeID,
                taskID = oneEvent.TaskID,
                ticketID = oneEvent.TicketID,
                loccoID = oneEvent.LoccoID,
                startTime = oneEvent.StartTime,
                endTime = oneEvent.EndTime,
                shiftFrom = oneEvent.ShiftFrom,
                shiftTo = oneEvent.ShiftTo,
                description = oneEvent.Description,
                billable = oneEvent.Billable
            };
            returnEvents.Add(newEvent);
        }
        return returnEvents;
    }
```

I tried displaying the events in fullcalendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'title',
        center: '',
        right: 'prev,next today basicDay,basicWeek,month',
    },

    //events: "/Calendar/GetEvents/", // not implemented
    events: "@Url.Action("GetCalendarEvents/")",
```

and outputing the result to console:

```
console.log("@Url.Action("GetCalendarEvents/")");
```

but I get:

```
VM84 Index:83 /Calendar/GetCalendarEvents/

fullcalendar.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined
```

Comment: Anything that can be serialized into JSON will work.  What is actually wrong with the JSON that is being returned?  Is it empty? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: What do you mean? What does not work? What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, I tried explaining my attempt at debugging

Comment: Try renaming  startTime to start and endTime to end. I think full calendar is expecting start and end not startTime and endTime.

Comment: What bothers me is that my console.log in the view also displays "/Calendar/GetCalendarEvents/" which makes no sense

Comment: have you tried just calling `/Calendar/GetCalendarEvents` in the browser, paste the url in the address bar or use Fiddler or Chromre REST tool

Comment: `@Url.Action` "generates a fully qualified URL to an action method" according to the documentation.

Comment: I don't think you want the trailing "/" on the end of your action name, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing some required fields.  If you look at the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/), `title`, `start` are **required**.  Try setting these in the class to start with and build from that...

```
public static List<Event> getAllEvents()
{
    List<DataLayer.Event> dbEvents = DataApi.db.Event.ToList();
    List<Event> returnEvents = new List<Event>();
    foreach (DataLayer.Event oneEvent in dbEvents)
    {
        Event newEvent = new Event
        {
            start = oneEvent.StartTime,
            title = oneEvent.Description // you may need to add this to your Event class.
        };
        returnEvents.Add(newEvent);
    }
    return returnEvents;
}
```

Also, instead of using *console* to log the *Json*, use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Chrome Advanced Tools

Comment: This got me rolling. Also one issue was that I was debugging the @Url.Action by trying to output it to browser console so it only displayer the  url. I still havent figured out on what level does the \@Url.Action get executed but it's slightly unrelated to this "specific" issue